# Get translations from SSAS with ADOMD.Net

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssas, adomd.net

What's the best way to read metadata (including translations) from the SSAS?
So far, ADOMD.Net came in quite handy but I cannot find a way to access translations.

I need to populate the metadata for a custom cube browser and cannot rely on SSAS to do the translations for me. Due to restrictions from our customers, the client application does not have direct access to the SSAS server but rather passes the MDX-queries through a linked sql server. Thereby SSAS is not able to determine the client machine's culture settings. This is why I would like to persist all metadata to an accessible database by using an SSAS Extension.

Long story short: How can I access translations which reside in SSAS by using C#?

Answer (score 0):

that's a strange requirement, I don't know how it can be done, but can you explain why do you go through all this trouble to access your cube? I can only imagine it has something to do with security. If so, I can advise you to look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492140.aspx) link that expains how to Configure HTTP Access to Analysis Services. The link is flagged on SQL 2012 but it works even on 2005 (I've done it)

Comment: Besides network restrictions obviously, one of the reasons is that we want to be able to enrich reports with relational data from the transactional databases by joining SQL and MDX queries; without having to pass all that data through SSAS. The application provides a GUI to create database queries based on metadata which we would like to extend with OLAP functionality.

Comment: Be aware you need a web-facing licence for SQL Server if exposing cube data online.